# Prettier doesn't work in VSCode with eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I want Prettier to auto format my code using eslint rules in VSCode but it shows this error:

> Failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'CLIOptions': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'
>   Require stack:
>   - C:\Dev\Tool\Microsoft VS Code__placeholder__.js

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^6.4.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2"
}
```

.eslint.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
      "commonjs": true,
      "es6": true,
      "node": true
  },
  "extends": "airbnb-base",
  "globals": {
      "Atomics": "readonly",
      "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2018
  },
  "rules": {
  }
};
```

Comment: you can run manually command to execute eslint functionlit ./node_modules/.bin/eslint.If you want these command execute using VScode so you can setup it manually. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: Personally and I think this is becoming more of a movement - to keep eslint distinctly for code problems and use a tool like prettier for style. That's worked nicely for me. I think airbnb is far too draconian with it's stylistic opinions (e.g. no for..of loops).

Comment: I guess I can live without having styling errors highlighted if prettier still does it's job without it.